# gradle project dependency on a distributed layout

Tags: layout, build, gradle, project, distributed

We have some old projects with Ant builds that are grouped in different directories. We're trying to convert them to gradle builds.

The repo has a structure like the following where let say that all the WebComponent projects depend on DbComponent projects so they are not in hierarchical layout neither in flat layout. I realize that in the longer run we probably want to publish DBComponent projects as artifacts but for the moment I was wondering if we it is possible to create a multi-project build where subprojects are not flat nor hierarchical. include and includeFlat with compile project do not seem to do the trick in this case.

Is this something that can work at all?

```
|-WebComponents

    |
    |
    |--project1

    |
    |--project2
    |
    |--project3
|
|
|-DbComponents
    |
    |--dbproj1
    |
    |--dbproj2
```

Thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Gradle can work with any layout; a custom layout just takes a bit more configuration than a hierarchical or flat layout. Anyway, what you have looks very much like a hierarchical layout, just two levels deep. In this case, the easiest solution is to use includes such as `include "WebComponents:project1"` and project dependencies such as `dependencies { compile project(":WebComponents:project1") }`.

Comment: project1 (under WebComponents folder - not project) need to have dbproj1 (under DbComponents folder - not project) as a dependency.  WebComponents and DbComponents are sibbling folders. What you are suggesting is not doing the trick of first going up the hierarchy and then coming down.

Comment: I guess what I am not understanding is how do you go up the hierarchy.

Comment: Should be as simple as `compile project(":DbComponents:dbproj1")`. That's an absolute path, from the root of the (logical) hierarchy. (Gradle differentiates between logical (always hierarchical) and physical project paths, but in your case they are the same (if you use includes as I showed).)

Comment: Studying the "multi-project builds chapter" in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) should help too.

Comment: I'll study it more carefully. I did go through it once but maybe I missed something.  I did study more carefully the chapter from Gradle Effective Implementation Guide book.